# JavaScript user input variable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

n00b here!

I have managed to assemble JavaScript code and I don't understand why is not working correct.

The code is designed to calculate the difference between a given date and today's date. I guess my logic in the script is not correct as no error show in the console.

Here is the code:

```js
function setDate(){
    let thedate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    if (thedate){
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = thedate;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = "No Date set";
    }
} 

let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

var startDate  = startDate; // Start Date 
var endDate    = today; // Today's Date
{
var diffInMs   = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate)
var diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = ("Day: ") + diffInDays; // Day Counter 
var diffInWeeks = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = ("Week: ") + (diffInWeeks).toFixed(); // Week Counter 
if (diffInWeeks < 4) {
  stageStatus = ("<i class=\"fas fa-seedling\" ></i>  Vegetation");
} else if (diffInWeeks > 6) {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-pepper-hot\" ></i> Harvesting";
} else {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-leaf\" ></i> Flowering";
}
document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = stageStatus;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</head>  
<body>


<div class="card bg-secondary  border-dark m-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT--> 
 <input type="date" id="startDate" ><br>
  <button onclick="setDate()">Set Date</button>
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT END-->  

<!-- SHOW THE CHOOSEN DATE-->
<p id="showinputhere"></p>
<!-- CHOOSEN DATE END-->

<!--DISPLAY DAY & WEEK-->
<div class="card-body text-center">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="days" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="weeks" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!--DAY & WEEK END-->
   
<!--STAGE START-->
<div class="alert alert-success m-3" role="alert">
  <span class="h4"><p id="stage" class="mb-0"></p></span>
</div>  
<!--STAGE END-->
 </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to get the user to input the start date and from there all the magic shoud happen, unfortinanlty it only works when I hardcode the date here: `var startDate  = startDate; // Start Date`  like so:`var startDate  = "2022/01/01"; // Start Date`

Here is the working JavaScript without user input the date:

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

var startDate  = "2022/01/01"; // Start Date 
var endDate    = today; // Today's Date
{
var diffInMs   = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate)
var diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = ("Day: ") + diffInDays; // Day Counter 
var diffInWeeks = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = ("Week: ") + (diffInWeeks).toFixed(); // Week Counter 
if (diffInWeeks < 4) {
  stageStatus = ("<i class=\"fas fa-seedling\" ></i>  Vegetation");
} else if (diffInWeeks > 6) {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-pepper-hot\" ></i> Harvesting";
} else {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-leaf\" ></i> Flowering";
}
document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = stageStatus;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</head>  
<body>


<div class="card bg-secondary  border-dark m-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT 
 <input type="date" id="startDate" ><br>
  <button onclick="setDate()">Set Date</button>
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT END-->  

<!--SHOW THE CHOOSEN DATE
<p id="showinputhere"></p>
 CHOOSEN DATE END-->

<!--DISPLAY DAY & WEEK-->
<div class="card-body text-center">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="days" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="weeks" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!--DAY & WEEK END-->
   
<!--STAGE START-->
<div class="alert alert-success m-3" role="alert">
  <span class="h4"><p id="stage" class="mb-0"></p></span>
</div>  
<!--STAGE END-->
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: The correct debugging steps here would be to take the two values and see what happens when you convert them to dates, then work through your calculation until you find NaNs (which you should find right away, thus making the majority of the code in this question not necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some adjusts to calcule the flowering days:

```js
document.getElementById('startDate').valueAsDate = new Date();
calcule();

function calcule() {
  let date = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
  var diffInMs = new Date() - new Date(date);
  var diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var labelDay = diffInDays > 2 ? "Days: " : "Day: ";
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = labelDay + Math.round(diffInDays * 100) / 100; // Day Counter 
  var diffInWeeks = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
  var labelWeek = diffInDays > 2 ? "Weeks: " : "Week: ";
  document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = labelWeek + (diffInWeeks).toFixed(); // Week Counter 
  if (diffInWeeks < 4) {
    stageStatus = ("<i class=\"fas fa-seedling\" ></i>  Vegetation");
  } else if (diffInWeeks > 6) {
    stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-pepper-hot\" ></i> Harvesting";
  } else {
    stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-leaf\" ></i> Flowering";
  }
  document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = stageStatus;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card bg-secondary  border-dark m-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
  <!--SET START DATE USER INPUT-->
  <input type="date" id="startDate" onchange="calcule()"><br>

  <!--DISPLAY DAY & WEEK-->
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m-auto">
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
          <h4>
            <p id="days" class="mb-0"></p>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col m-auto">
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
          <h4>
            <p id="weeks" class="mb-0"></p>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--DAY & WEEK END-->

    <!--STAGE START-->
    <div class="alert alert-success m-3" role="alert">
      <span class="h4"><p id="stage" class="mb-0"></p></span>
    </div>
    <!--STAGE END-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setDate(){
    let thedate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    if (thedate){
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = thedate;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = "No Date set";
    }
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

var startDate  = thedate; // Start Date 
var endDate    = today; // Today's Date
var diffInMs   = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate)
var diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = ("Day: ") + diffInDays; // Day Counter 
var diffInWeeks = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = ("Week: ") + (diffInWeeks).toFixed(); // Week Counter 
if (diffInWeeks < 4) {
  stageStatus = ("<i class=\"fas fa-seedling\" ></i>  Vegetation");
} else if (diffInWeeks > 6) {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-pepper-hot\" ></i> Harvesting";
} else {
  stageStatus = "<i class=\"fas fa-leaf\" ></i> Flowering";
}
document.getElementById("stage").innerHTML = stageStatus;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</head>  
<body>


<div class="card bg-secondary  border-dark m-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT--> 
 <input type="date" id="startDate" ><br>
  <button onclick="setDate()">Set Date</button>
<!--SET START DATE USER INPUT END-->  

<!-- SHOW THE CHOOSEN DATE-->
<p id="showinputhere"></p>
<!-- CHOOSEN DATE END-->

<!--DISPLAY DAY & WEEK-->
<div class="card-body text-center">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="days" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col m-auto">
    <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert"><h4><p id="weeks" class="mb-0"></p></h4></div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!--DAY & WEEK END-->
   
<!--STAGE START-->
<div class="alert alert-success m-3" role="alert">
  <span class="h4"><p id="stage" class="mb-0"></p></span>
</div>  
<!--STAGE END-->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't realize there `startDate` was out of a block of your function and you also have to pass `thedate` to `startDate`